# specFlow web interface

Tags: web-applications, nunit, specflow

Is anyone aware of a web application that can run SpecFlow or NUnit tests? Basicly, I have my customers defining acceptance tests, and I would like them to be able to execute the tests they have defined against a staging server.

Been looking about, and I can find a few old dead projects like Nunit Web, but I have not found anything that really meets my requirements.

Comment: TeamCity by JetBrains is a web interface can run nunit tests, have you looked into it and is this what you mean?

Comment: yes I use team city anyway. I was hoping for something a little more customer orientated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few links to specflow tools that might be of interest.

From the Specflow website:

**[SpecLog](http://www.speclog.net/)**

SpecLog is a collaborative tool by TechTalk for agile requirement engineering with strong integration to SpecFlow and ALM tools (currently for Team Foundation Server, Visual Studio Online and JIRA).

Feature files are linked from source-control repositories to context of the other specification artifacts, like user stories or business goals.

SpecLog allows visualizing and structuring Gherkin feature files in maps (e.g. Story Maps, Impact Maps, functional tree) and to extend feature files with further documentation artifacts like pictures, links and additional documents. This helps providing a more comprehensive living documentation and enhances readability of Gherkin scenarios.

This documentation can be also exported to HTML, which makes it easier to share with stakeholders, and allows linking Gherkin scenarios with other documentation systems (e.g. operations manual, user reference, etc.). SpecLog also allows working offline to support users that are only occasionally connected to a network.

---

**[fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/)**

The fully integrated standalone wiki and acceptance testing framework

The wiki pages created in FitNesse are run as tests. The specifications can be tested against the application itself, resulting in a roundtrip between specifications and implementation.

---

**[Behave for JIRA](http://hindsightsoftware.com/solutions/behave-for-jira/)**

Is a jira plugin to hook specflow into JIRA.